# Does a validator/linter for Google's HTML/CSS/JS style guides exist?

Tags: javascript, html, css, coding-style, google-style-guide

I've been looking around for ages, but I can't seem to find any validators for these. I'm looking for similar to [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer).

I'm talking about the following style guides:

- [HTML/CSS](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html)
- [JavaScript](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)

Does anybody know of one (or some)? Am I just not looking properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean something like this? https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the linter in your IDE to use the [google style guide](https://github.com/google/eslint-config-google).

create or edit your package,json with:

```
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": "google"
 }
```

and then install the packages that your IDE will use to lint.
( your IDE will use node to lint, e.g. [sublimelinter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter) with [contrib-eslint](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint)  )